# Profile look up (freecodecamp) challenge

Tags: javascript

[image]

With this FreeCodeCamp problem I was stuck for ages but managed to get through it when I changed:

```
if(contacts[i].firstName === name)
```

to

```
if(contacts[i].name === firstName)
```

Not sure why switching `name` and `firstName` around worked, can someone explain why? 
update: added entire code for clarity:

```
//Setup
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
// Only change code below this line
for (var i =0; i <contacts.length; i++) {
    if(contacts[i].firstName === name) {
    if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        return contacts[i][prop];
    } else
        return "No such property";   
    }
}
    return "No such contact"
// Only change code above this line
}

// Change these values to test your function
lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");
```

Comment: I am surprised this works since `firstName` doesn't appear to be declared anywhere. Is this all the code? Can you add it as text instead of an image as well?

Comment: Just added the text format of my code

Comment: The code that you pasted works fine. Are you asking about why the code you pasted works and why the code in the image doesn't?

Comment: yes exactly what I'm asking. it's probably something really basic but I can't wrap my head around why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with using the following `if` statement:

```
if(contacts[i].name === firstName)
```

The first issue is that you are trying to use `firstName` as a *variable*. There is no variable in your code called `firstName` and so you'll get an error when you try to use it as one. Instead, `firstName` is a *property* of an object in your array (not to be confused with a standalone variable). This means you can only access `firstName` with reference to an object in your array.

The second issue with the above code is `contacts[i].name`. In this part of your code `contacts[i]` is referring to the `ith` object in your code. You are then trying to access the `name` property of this given object. However, none of your objects have a `name` property - they have a `firstName` property, but don't have a `name` property. So, when you try and access a property/key that isn't in your object, you'll get `undefined` back.

The valid code to use is:

```
if(contacts[i].firstName === name)
```

as `firstName` *is* a property of your object (which you are accessing with reference to your object - `contacts[i]`)  and `name` is a variable (an argument of the function) which can be used without any problems.

Comment: THANKS A BUNCH! you clearly explained it so well cheers Nick!!

Comment: @NhiemTran no worries, glad I could help :)

Comment: Oh I see, I'm new to stackoverflow and didn't know you could do that. Just marked yours as the correct answer. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking that. So this was the code that made me pass.

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
// Only change code below this line
for (var i =0; i <contacts.length; i++) {
    if(contacts[i].firstName === name) {
    if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        return contacts[i][prop];
    } else
        return "No such property";   
    }
}
    return "No such contact"
// Only change code above this line
}

// Change these values to test your function
lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");
```